# Factorization of $ x^2 +xy+5x+m+5 $

Tags: polynomials

I want to factorize $ x^2 +xy+5x+m+5 $ . For what value of m ,  $ x^2 +xy+5x+m+5 $ can be resolved into linear factors ?

My try  : 
  $ x^2 +xy+5x+m+5 $ = $ x^2 +(5+y)x+(m+5) $

To get the linear factors , we must have the determinant of this eqn is >= 0 .

D = $ (5+y)^2-4(m+5)$ . Then I can not proceed .

Comment: You want to factor over the rational integers, $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-straight-line/pair-of-straight-lines/

Comment: I want to factor over the real number .

Comment: If it factors, it factors as $(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)$ for some real $a,b,c,d,e,f$. $b$ and $e$ can't both be zero; say $b\ne0$. Then $e=f=0$. So we are talking $dx(ax+by+c)$, so we need $m=-5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why did you put this as a comment when it is clearly an answer?

Comment: @TBrendle, I don't know. I'm sure I had a good reason at the time.

Comment: Yes . @labbhattacharjee , Many many thanks . I have done it .

Comment: @Waytoinfinity, nice to hear that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that factoring we will expect the factors to be of the form:
$$(x+\alpha y + \beta)(x+\gamma y + \delta)$$
Comparing the coefficient of $y^2$ gives us $\alpha \gamma = 0$. Due to symmetry, let us set $\gamma =0$. Hence, we will expect the factors to be of the form:
$$(x+\alpha y + \beta)(x + \delta)$$
Now comparing the coefficient of $y$, we get that
$$\alpha \delta = 0$$
If $\alpha = 0$, there will be no $y$ term. Hence, $\delta = 0$. Hence, the factorization has to be of the form
$$(x+\alpha y + \beta)x$$
Hence, $m+5 = 0 \implies m=-5$.

Answer (score 1):

Since now you want to have the discriminant greater than $0$ which in itself is a quadratic polynomial ie $y^2+10y+(5-4m)$ . We see that this will be always greater than $0$ . If its discriminant is always less than $0$ . Because if a quadratic has real roots than it will be positive and negative .

The determinant of $y^2+10y+(5-4m)$ is $ D = 100 -4(5-4m) $ = $80+16m$

Now $D=0$ => $ 80+16m = 0 $ =>$ m = -5 $

Comment: I have understood your method . It is more charming .

Comment: Nice to hear that :) !